# SSLv3 ServerKeyExchange SIgnature struct mismatch

Tags: tls

Im playing with implementing SSLv3 in Go according to [rfc6101](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6101).

I can deserialize ServerKeyExchange until ServerKeyExchange.signed_params.

The cipher suite is `TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 (0x0003)`.

The Certificate signature algo: `1.2.840.113549.1.1.5 (sha1WithRSAEncryption)`.

According to the RFC the structs should look like this:

```
        struct {
            select (KeyExchangeAlgorithm) {
                case diffie_hellman:
                    ServerDHParams params;
                    Signature signed_params;
                case rsa:
                    ServerRSAParams params;
                    Signature signed_params;
                case fortezza_kea:
                    ServerFortezzaParams params;
            };
        } ServerKeyExchange;
```

```
        digitally-signed struct {
            select(SignatureAlgorithm) {
                case anonymous: struct { };
                case rsa:
                    opaque md5_hash[16];
                    opaque sha_hash[20];
                case dsa:
                    opaque sha_hash[20];
            };
        } Signature;
```

but i got a different response form the server:

[image]

What i am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: **Disagree with VtC as 'programming'**; although OP is writing code, the Q is not about the code but about the protocol independent of any implementation, and does not belong on SO. It _is_ 'use' of crypto as opposed to crypto itself, and might be better on security.SX, but I'd call it borderline.

Answer (score 1):

About 10 lines above the part you quoted, there is

```
        struct {
            opaque rsa_modulus<1..2^16-1>;
            opaque rsa_exponent<1..2^16-1>;
        } ServerRSAParams;
```

so the case=`rsa` (which is actually only for rsa_export) of `ServerKeyExchange` is really:

```
        ServerRSAParams:
            rsa_modulus -- opaque (really bigendian unsigned integer)
            rsa_exponent -- ditto
        Signature -- ditto
```

but this structuring doesn't affect the encoding, which contains only the three 'leaf' values, and whatever decode you are looking at (Wireshark?) doesn't bother to distinguish the two levels here.

Note `digitally-signed struct ... Signature` does not mean the two hashes (md5 and sha1) are contained in the message; rather they are input to the applicable signature generation algorithm, in this case RSA 'block type 1' defined in PKCS1v1 (now retronymed RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 in PKCS1v2), and the *output* of the signature algorithm, for RSA a single integer encoded as bigendian unsigned fixed-length (see 'I2OSP' in any version of PKCS1), is what is placed in the message, with a 2-byte length prefix, as it if were declared `opaque<?..2^16-1>` although I don't see this stated in RFC6101; TLS1.0 RFC2246 et succ does state it in 4.7.

(You might want to look at more/all of RFC2246; except for the PRF and key derivation, some alert codes and ciphersuites, the addition of extensions (of which RFC5746 Secure Renegotiation became pretty much mandatory) and of course the version number, to the best of my recollection TLS1.0 is technically the same as SSL3, but the document is more thorough, probably due to going through the IETF gauntlet^Wprocess.)